# I cannot delete a contact due to "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Tags: apex, contact, failing-tests, before-trigger, npsp

I have this trigger:

```
trigger deleteContactReceiver on Contact (before delete) 
{
    List<Contact> con=Trigger.new;
    GDPRContact.deleteContactURN(con); 
}
```

**Invokes:**

```
public static void deleteContactURN(List<Contact> con)
    { 
    for(Contact c:con)
        {
            try
                    {
                List<TWAM_URN__c> preURN=[select URN__c, TWAM_SFID__c, TWAM_Last_Name__c, TWAM_URN_Allocation_Time__c, TWAM_URN_Is_Assigned__c from TWAM_URN__c where TWAM_SFID__c=:c.TWAM_SFID__c];
                preURN.get(0).TWAM_SFID__c='';
                System.debug('**** URN IS="+preURN.get(0).TWAM_SFID__c+" ****: ');
                preURN.get(0).TWAM_Last_Name__c='';
                preURN.get(0).TWAM_URN_Allocation_Time__c=null;
                preURN.get(0).TWAM_URN_Is_Assigned__c=FALSE;
                update preURN;
                }    
            catch(Exception e) 
                {
                System.debug('**** An unexpected error has occurred ****: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
           }  // end for 

}
```

**The testMethod I'm trying to execute is:**

```
public static testMethod void deleteContact()
        {
        Test.startTest();
        Contact con1=new Contact();
        con1=[select Id, AccountId from Contact where Id='0031o00001TWS6RAAX'];
        delete con1;
        List<TWAM_URN__c> postURN2=[select TWAM_SFID__c,TWAM_URN_Is_Assigned__c from TWAM_URN__c where TWAM_SFID__c=:con1.Id LIMIT 1];
        System.assertEquals(FALSE, postURN2.get(0).TWAM_URN_Is_Assigned__c);
        System.assertEquals(null, postURN2.get(0).TWAM_SFID__c);

        Test.stopTest();
        }
```

The line throwing the error is highlighted in bold. A single row in the DB does exist, verified by looking at debug logs.  I know I should not deploy like this as I may have a list of contacts, just trying to get some code working.

Comment: Sorry the line throwing the error is "delete con1;"

Comment: How are you querying for a hard-coded Id in a test method? It looks to me like there are other issues in play.

Comment: I use the code "con1=[select Id, AccountId from Contact where Id='0031o00001TWS6RAAX'];".  I should definitely not did this for live use, just wanted to get a test working.

Comment: Your test can't see that contact. It's isolated from the real database. See Joe's answer. If you're using seeAllData, please consider refactoring and not doing that. It's very bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot see the line you have highlighted in bold, however I think the problem is probably that you are trying to access records from the org that will not exist in a test environment. As by default your org data is not visible to test methods.

So when you are assigning the contact variable "con1" the value of the soql query it is finding nothing and giving a null value, then giving you the error.

Instead you should create a contact in the test code and use that contact instead of querying for one.

Comment: The line is "delete con1".  The contact id does exists in the database.  I use an SOQL console to run the exact same query on the org and the correct row is returned.  In the debug log I get this:  
    14:27:33.744 (8746588083)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[54]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = '0031o00001TWS6RAAX'
    14:27:33.744 (8757275090)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[54]|Rows:1
    14:27:33.744 (8757496471)|USER_DEBUG|[56]|DEBUG|**** TEST 0031o00001TWS6RAAX ****
    14:27:33.744 (8757537471)|DML_BEGIN|[58]|Op:Delete|Type:Contact|Rows:1